# Cinnamon: How to position popupmenu?

Tags: gui, cinnamon, style

I'm new to cinnamon desktop, I used gnome session fallback and mate before. What I'm trying to achieve is the following: when I right click on a window on the panel, the popupmenu should be right above the place I clicked. But for some reason the popupmenu is designed in a way that its left corner is positioned to the center of that window switcher thing. But I'd like to move it to the left side.

So basically:

[image: what i want]

I think it could be done by editing popupMenu.js but I'm not sure how. I didn't find anything relevant in css files. Any thoughts?

(I'm on ubuntu 16.04, cinnamon 3.0.7)

Comment: Could you link to a paste of the JS file?

Comment: @Zacharee1 https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/blob/master/js/ui/popupMenu.js

Comment: Bounty ends in 3 days

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I clicked the notification and then was pulled away.

Comment: OK. On line 2582, see if replacing `Math.round(sourceX)` with `0` and then rebooting helps.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Stays the same :-(

Comment: However I determined that [this line](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/blob/86e14ef1000adcf6b21b98e3addf279c6dfe159c/js/ui/popupMenu.js#L2150) is relevant in this case instead. But setting the first parameter to 0 causes the menu disappear entirely

Comment: I'll look around it when I can